# Required foreign keys in EF Core & sqlite not working for type long

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core, foreign-key-relationship

I use Entity Framework Core code first with these two related tables:

```
public class Teacher
{
  [Key]
  public long Id { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
  [Key]
  public long Id { get; set; }

  [Required]
  public long TeacherId { get; set; }
  public Teacher Teacher { get; set; }
}
```

On an empty database the following insert will fail with `SQLite Error 19: 'FOREIGN KEY constraint failed'` since there is no teacher with Id 123456:

```
var student = new Student();
student.TeacherId = 123456;
dbcontext.Add(student);
dbcontext.SaveChanges();
```

I would expect the following to fail, too, but it does not throw an error. Instead it will add a student without relation:

```
var student = new Student();
student.TeacherId = 0; // why is this allowed??
dbcontext.Add(student);
dbcontext.SaveChanges();
```

Since there is no teacher with Id 0 I want this second code sample to fail, too. I thought `[require]` would get EF core /sqlite to really require the relation and am surprised why adding the student with foreign key 0 does not throw an error.

How do I get ef core / sqlite to really require the relation?

Comment: can you throw up the migration if there is one? something is fishy I agree.  Seems like its attempting to graph a teacher at 0 at the same time student is created.

Comment: I got FK violation exception for 2nd code too. Are you sure that your code is setup correctly as shown in above question.

Comment: @Smit, I'm quite sure, yes. Did you use sqlite or some full SQL server?

Comment: I used SQLite db